# Reactjs onclick increment counter variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**CONTEXT:** I have  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx0Uw.png) shape which is mainly built from 20x20 px MUI Boxes which are using a react component(Cell).Whenever a cell is clicked it's state ( color ) is changed.

**Problem :** I tried creating a variable called count which gets incremented everytime a cell's wrapper is clicked and lately  display the total amount of red cells (clicked cells) inside a footer wrapper . Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working

**Looking for :** A way to count only one time each cell clicked and display it inside footer.

```js
// =====================================================================================================================
//  C O M P O N E N T
// =====================================================================================================================

class Cell extends React.Component {
    state = {
        color: '#bbdefb',
    };

    onChange = () => {
        this.setState({color: 'red'});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: this.state.color,
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    opacity: '60%',
                    outlineStyle: 'solid',
                    outlineWidth: '1px',
                    outlineColor: '#1a237e',
                }}
                onClick={this.onChange}
            />
        );
    }
}

class Main extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <Box sx={SX.root}>
                <Box sx={SX.page}>
                    <MathGrid sx={SX.math1} />
                    <Box sx={SX.firstrow} onClick={handleCount}>
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                    </Box>
                    <Box sx={SX.secondrow} onClick={handleCount}>
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                    </Box>
                    <Box sx={SX.thirdrow} onClick={handleCount}>
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                    </Box>
                    <Box sx={SX.forthrow} onClick={handleCount}>
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                    </Box>
                </Box>
                <Box sx={SX.header} />
                <Box sx={SX.footer}>
                    <Box sx={SX.counter}>{count}</Box>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        );
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  I N T E R N A L
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
const handleCount = () => {
    count++;
};
// =====================================================================================================================
//  E X P O R T
// =====================================================================================================================
export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the `count` variable is defined in the module scope. The `render` method didn't execute again because you didn't use `this.setState()`. This means your component didn't re-render.

You should define `count` as a state of the `Main` component, and the `render` method will be executed when you call set new state:

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
  state = {count: 0}
  handleCount = () => {
    this.setState({ count: count+1 });
  };
  render() {
    //...
  }
}
```